# Which Role(RABC) should I add to a user in Azure SQL to allow him access using SSMS?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, ssms

Im trying to grant users access to my Azure SQL, so they could connect using Sql Management Studio.

Which RBAC (role-based access control) roles should I assign them and How?

Thanks

Comment: You do you require any special RBAC's to allow users to connect to a database as long as they have valid credentials and are authorized to connect to the DB instance . You would require group level (or user-level) permissions to create a mesh of priviliges to allow deterministic access to SQL objects such as views, tables, procedures et.al.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a new login and user created, they all could connect using SSMS, the difference is if the new user has the permission to access or alter the database.

Azure SQL database has administrator user and non-administrator user.

For more details, you can reference this document:[Controlling and granting database access to SQL Database and SQL Data Warehouse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins).

You can grant the use different permission or alter it's role in database to control the access of Azure SQL Database with admin account.

Reference:

1. [ALTER ROLE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-role-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).
2. [ALTER USER (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to azure ad user to access Azure sql, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure#using-an-azure-ad-identity-to-connect-using-ssms-or-ssdt